# Wireless Woes: iwlwifi-8265 - Ubuntu 18.04 (and Mint Tara)

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, iwlwifi

I am trying to set up two machines, both have identical hardware that should be supported by the newer Linux kernels.  The wireless card inside is a GIGABYTE "GC-WB867D-I" Wifi+Bluetooth.  Out of the box the Bluetooth works, however the Wifi does not.

---

The **kerenel** version via: `uname -r`

`5.0.0-31-generic`

The **firmware** version via: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 8265`

`firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode`

The firmware **file code** via: `lsmod | grep iwlwifi`

`iwlwifi               315392  1 iwlmvm`

The **Network controller** via: `sudo lspci | grep Network`

`41:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)`

---

The more **verbose Network controller** via ID: `sudo lspci -vnd 8086:24fd`

`41:00.0 0280: 8086:24fd (rev 78)
    Subsystem: 8086:1010
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 139
    Memory at fa400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 48-89-e7-ff-ff-4b-c6-c0
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl`

And finally the most verbose via the **debug script**: `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info`

Text file excerpt:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 14 Oct 2019 20:53 PDT -0700

Booted last: 14 Oct 2019 00:00 PDT -0700

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: igb

41:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:1010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 05b8:3279 Agiler, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0108  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy3: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6447104  0
iwlmvm                389120  0
rtl8xxxu              126976  0
mac80211              819200  2 iwlmvm,rtl8xxxu
iwlwifi               315392  1 iwlmvm
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
cfg80211              679936  4 wl,iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi                    28672  3 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

etc.... etc....

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########


##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager


etc.... etc....


##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/debug: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_agg_pages: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_aggregation: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_agg_timeout: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/ht40_2g: Permission denied
[rtl8xxxu]

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
d0i3_timeout: 1000
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
enable_ini: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00
```

---

*~EDIT~* The loading of the kernel module. `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    5.761509] iwlwifi 0000:41:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.765276] iwlwifi 0000:41:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.9f0a2d68.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.836664] iwlwifi 0000:41:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    5.843363] iwlwifi 0000:41:00.0: swiotlb buffer is full (sz: 4096 bytes)
[    5.843367] iwlwifi 0000:41:00.0: overflow 0x0000001030d6f000+4096 of DMA mask fffffffff bus mask 0
[    5.843377] Modules linked in: snd_pcm ucsi_ccg(+) wl(POE) aes_x86_64 snd_seq_midi crypto_simd snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm(+) cryptd rtl8xxxu(+) glue_helper joydev input_leds typec_ucsi fjes(-) snd_rawmidi video typec mac80211 ttm iwlwifi drm_kms_helper snd_seq btusb wmi_bmof btrtl mxm_wmi btbcm snd_seq_device drm btintel snd_timer cfg80211 bluetooth fb_sys_fops snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ecdh_generic sysimgblt k10temp ccp(+) soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid igb i2c_algo_bit nvme ahci dca i2c_piix4 nvme_core i2c_nvidia_gpu libahci gpio_amdpt wmi gpio_generic
[    5.843419]  iwl_pcie_rxq_alloc_rbs+0x164/0x1d0 [iwlwifi]
[    5.843425]  _iwl_pcie_rx_init+0x2bc/0x310 [iwlwifi]
[    5.843431]  iwl_pcie_rx_init+0x2d/0x400 [iwlwifi]
[    5.843442]  ? iwl_mvm_nic_config+0x118/0x170 [iwlmvm]
[    5.843449]  iwl_trans_pcie_start_fw+0x2a1/0x6d0 [iwlwifi]
[    5.843459]  ? iwl_init_notification_wait+0x6d/0xb0 [iwlwifi]
[    5.843467]  iwl_mvm_load_ucode_wait_alive+0x102/0x310 [iwlmvm]
[    5.843476]  iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x88/0x340 [iwlmvm]
[    5.843483]  ? iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x88/0x340 [iwlmvm]
[    5.843490]  ? iwl_wait_init_complete+0x30/0x30 [iwlmvm]
[    5.843497]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x72e/0xab0 [iwlmvm]
[    5.843504]  ? iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x72e/0xab0 [iwlmvm]
[    5.843510]  _iwl_op_mode_start.isra.10+0x4c/0xa0 [iwlwifi]
[    5.843516]  iwl_opmode_register+0x75/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[    5.843525]  iwl_mvm_init+0x38/0x1000 [iwlmvm]
[    6.884065] iwlwifi 0000:41:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x3, CPU2 Status: 0x2a58
[    6.884069] iwlwifi 0000:41:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    6.884071] iwlwifi 0000:41:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    7.233236] iwlwifi 0000:41:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

---

**What I have tried...**

---

Replace the `iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode` file in `/lib/firmware/` folder with the [drivers from Intel](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi).  The folder contains, iwlwifi-8265 (-21), (-22), (-27), (-31), (-34), (-36) for newer kerenls I'd assume.

---

Changed the power settings via gedit, `wifi.powersave = 3` (3) -> (2) -> (1) in file`/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

---

Updated, upgraded, updated kernels etc...  I am usually okay at troubleshooting linux issues, however this one has me stumped.  I noticed the firmware version points to `iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode`, while the Intel driver points to `iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode`.  Is this the issue?

---

I have lost a day to this problem, and normally I can solve these issues somewhat quickly.  With any luck I can solve the issue within the next day, else I will buy two new PCI cards :<.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, one machine has Ubuntu, the other Mint.  Both have the same issue.

Comment: Your except omits the most useful part. Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Added the section under ~EDIT~, and it throws a "Failed to run INIT ucode: -110" error.  I will look into this next.  Thank you @chili555 your feedback on various forums has helped me for years, troubleshoot wireless issues on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. I don't have an answer but I suggest that you reset the BIOS/EFI to default and check again: `dmesg | grep iwl` I'd be Googling: `swiotlb buffer is full (sz: 4096 bytes)` and also: `overflow 0x0000001030d6f000+4096 of DMA mask` Is the BIOS/EFI fully updated? That's all I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** To change the PCIe slot on the MoBo **from** the PCIe x 16, **to** the PCIe x 8 slot.

---

**Because:** I'm not a linux expert, so correct me if this sounds fishy.  The `swiotlb buffer` is MoBo to chip level communication.  The error of `overflow 0x0000001030d6f000+4096 of DMA mask fffffffff bus mask 0` was due to the MoBo sending out a 16x mask.

---

**Notes:** Hope this can help someone!!!

Here is the hardware that was in use. [MoBo](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/kydxFT/gigabyte-x399-aorus-pro-atx-tr4-motherboard-x399-aorus-pro) and [Wifi Card](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/tTdqqs/gigabyte-wireless-network-card-gcwb867di)